# Atribuir altura do <ol> do CSS, para que o texto não evolva o número

Tags: css

Preciso fazer uma lista de tópicos com a numeração do lado, usei o  do html para fazer isso, só que não estou conseguindo fazer ficar como a imagem a abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo assim

```css
.numeros_cases, ol{
    list-style:none;
    counter-reset:item;
}
.numeros_cases, ol li{
    counter-increment:item;
}
.numeros_cases, ol li:before {
    content: counter(item);
    color: #f7931e;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.numeros_cases, li{
 margin-top:20px;
 width:auto;

}

.numeros_cases {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.titulo_borda_cases {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7931e;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    
}
.titulo_cases {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numeros_cases">
   <li>O fator <strong>“personalização” </strong>no segmento foi identificado como <strong>oportunidade </strong>de agregar valor ao produto explorando como “novidade”.</li>
   <li>Explorar as <strong>Cores </strong>das garrafas que comunicam com o público-alvo (predominância feminina).</li>
   <li>CO nome deveria remeter ao consumidor a sensação de algo <strong>moderno </strong>e de qualidade superior com um viés de <strong>produto “importado”</strong>.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue fazendo uma combinação de vários estilos no elemento `<ol>` e `<li>`, como `position: absolute;`, `position: relative;`, `left`, `top`, `margin-top` entre outros.

Tive que refazer seu código pois havia muita redundância, como por exemplo:

Em vez de `.numeros_cases, ol{`, basta apenas `.numeros_cases{`, já que esta classe já é o `<ol>`.

Vamos ao que interessa. Veja abaixo o efeito que gostaria com o código otimizado:

```css
html, body{ background: #555;  }

.numeros_cases{
    list-style:none;
    counter-reset:item;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 35px;

    padding-left: 50px;
}
.numeros_cases li{
   counter-increment:item;
   margin-top:20px;
   width: 100%;
   
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
}
.numeros_cases li:before {
   content: counter(item);
   color: #f7931e;
   font-size: 60px;
   
   position: absolute;
   left: -50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -25px;
}

.titulo_borda_cases {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7931e;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    
}
.titulo_cases {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numeros_cases">
  <li>O fator <strong>“personalização” </strong>no segmento foi identificado como <strong>oportunidade </strong>de agregar valor ao produto explorando como “novidade”.</li>
  <li>Explorar as <strong>Cores </strong>das garrafas que comunicam com o público-alvo (predominância feminina).</li>
  <li>CO nome deveria remeter ao consumidor a sensação de algo <strong>moderno </strong>e de qualidade superior com um viés de <strong>produto “importado”</strong>.</li>
</ol>
```